# Ruby: how to pass object to a block and return a calculated value depending on the obj?

Tags: ruby, object, timestamp, parameter-passing, block

I would like to do something similar:

```
seconds=Time.parse("0:26:29.489").magic{|z| z.hour+z.min+z.sec+z.nsec.fdiv(1_000_000)}
```

to convert a timestamp into seconds (with fractions too), instead of writing:

```
d=Time.parse("0:26:29.489")
seconds=d.hour+d.min+d.sec+d.nsec.fdiv(1_000_000)
```

to spare a temporary "d" variable. But what should I use for "magic" if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has `tap`, but that won't help you here.  What you want is something that would be called `pipe`, but sadly it's not there.  At least not without [a gem that monkey patches Object](https://github.com/hopsoft/pipe_envy).  Though I think it should be.

You can create a lambda and immediately call it, which will avoid the intermediate variable (or at least contain it within the lambda's block scope, as in your `magic` example), but I'm not sure you gain much, and would probably stick with what you have.  The lambda approach would look like this:

```
# will return the value for "seconds"
->(d) { d.hour+d.min+d.sec+d.nsec.fdiv(1_000_000) }.(Time.parse("0:26:29.489"))
```